# How to make an accurate map?

Tags: slam, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like the slam algorithm is really tricky. I tried in my living room and it works fine(demo: https://youtu.be/ml_pgbPEIz8 and https://youtu.be/yCTHY2m6ByE, there are happening roughly the same time).  However I tried in some rooms in my school, since I want to do a demo of navigation for students, it doesn't work well. I tried in a room with hard floor and a room with rough carpet. Both them doesn't give good map. I wonder if the slam algorithm itself doesn't work well for a simple small confined square shaped room, because it can't have a good prediction about its' location if all corners looks similar. The two rooms I tried are all standard college small classroom. The shapes are square and with lots of chairs in the middle.

What would be the best environment to demo slam? (I guess the best is hard floor room that's a little more complicated like this https://youtu.be/lkW4-dG2BCY) Are there good resources regarding to this problem?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270279/how-to-make-an-accurate-map?/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-09-05**:
Slam tends to do well in environments where the sensor can see the walls, and the walls and obstacles have some unique features. Putting a few large boxes in the middle of your classroom may help provide unique features.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2017-09-06**:
I would suggest you to use Hector SLAM which gives better maps for indoors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't say in your question, but from your video it looks like you're using `gmapping`. If you're driving your robot around like you are in the your second video while trying to map then you are driving and turning too fast. You need to drive and turn *slow*. You should also try going over any areas that don't look correct a couple of times, that may help.

Also, any chairs, desks, or tables may not completely turn up in your map because the laser can only see the legs and not tabletops/desktops. So, this may add to you're map looking incorrect as well. When I mapped out our lab I manually drew in the desks.

Check out [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/269280/how-to-make-better-maps-using-gmapping/?answer=269293#post-id-269293) for some more information. As @gvdhoorn points out in a comment to that answer, `gmapping` is quite old and you may want to try using other mapping components such as [Google Cartographer](http://wiki.ros.org/cartographer).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0